# How to update laravel core

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an application built on laravel 5.2 but there are some new changes made to the official repository. Whats the correct way of updating just the laravel core?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to update core only. I'd recommend you to update Laravel core and vendor packages with `composer update` command. It will update framework core and all vendor packages.

If you still want to update just core, I guess `composer update laravel/laravel` command will do exactly that.

Comment: Thanks for answering @alexey. But i was under the impression that composer update will first look into the composer lock file for the appropriate version, and just update the same version (if there are any changes to the same version).